# how to write a row number in matrix with horizontal line between rows

Tags: math-mode

I tried to make a horizontal line inside a matrix by the attached code. However, it did not work the compiling process gives a time out message. It work normally without the \hline command. Any help!

```
\documentclass[journal,draftcls,onecolumn,12pt,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\centering
W_b(1)=\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
\begin{block}{(ccccc)c}
 a      & b     &     &  &  & \matindex{\leftarrow d=0} \\
\ddots & \ddots&     &  &  & \matindex{\vdots} \\
   &     a & b   &  &  & \matindex{\ \ \ \   \leftarrow d=d_b-1} \\  
%\hline
 c      & d     &     &  &  & \matindex{\leftarrow d=d_b} \\  
\ddots &\ddots &     &  &  & \matindex{\vdots} \\
   &   c   &  d  &  &  & \matindex{\leftarrow d=D} 
\end{block}
\end{blockarray},
\label{eq:eq4} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not clear to me what you want the horizontal line to look like nd why it is not enough to use a normal `array` environment and `\hline` or `\cline`. Can you explain more clearly what you want?

Comment: What is the `\matindex` command, if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be in line with what you're after; setting the matrix and the row indices (your `\matindex`'s) as a separate `pmatrix` and `array` pair:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
  W_b(1) = \begin{pmatrix}
     a   &    b   &   \\
  \ddots & \ddots &   \\
         &    a   & b \\
  \hline
     c   &    d   &   \\
  \ddots & \ddots &   \\
         &    c   & d
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{array}{>{\scriptstyle} l}
    \leftarrow d = 0       \\
    \vdots                 \\
    \leftarrow d = d_b - 1 \\
    \leftarrow d = d_b     \\
    \vdots                 \\
    \leftarrow d = D
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I've chosen a `\scriptstyle` representation for the indices, but you could change this based on the true definition of `\matindex`. Additionally, the spacing between the `pmatrix` and indices can be changed (currently it's `\arraycolsep`).